# seaborn heatmap does not give the correct colors according to the cbar

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>>   control1    control2   control3
trt1  0.01         NaN        NaN
trt2  NaN          0.01       NaN
trt3  NaN          NaN        0.01
```

I have created a heatmap and defined that if values that are 0.01 and lower should be red. The problem is that they get the "p<.05" color:

```
ax= sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap,square=True,  linewidths=.3,linecolor="grey",cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.011,0.01])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['p<0.05', 'p<0.01'])
```

[image]

I have tried also to change the values in my original df instead of 0.01 to 0.001 but it still colored it in as "salmon" and not the red:tab.

**My endgoal is to get the correct color as the cbar displays.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `min` and the `max` values are the same in your dataframe `df`. So the `sns.heatmap()` has no range to apply the colormap on and will select the color in the middel of your `cmap`. If you don't change in input of your dataframe, you have to slice your `cmap` to the wanted color. Since you only want one color, your `cmap` can be a list with one string like this `cmap = ['red']`.

For your example `ax=sns.heatmap(df, cmap=['red'], square=True,  linewidths=.3)` will plot this:

[image: one color cmap]

**Update**

As a workaround, you can extend the `cmap`-color-list with the last value of the cmap. This should look like this `cmap = ['#DE0A0A'] + cmap`.

A simple example returns:

```
ax= sns.heatmap(df, cmap = ['#DE0A0A', '#DE0A0A', '#FF7C4B'], square=True,  linewidths=.3)
```

[image: adapted cmap]

Comment: thanl you for your answer. I understand what you mean. but in your example  the cbaar does not display the two colors, so the values colored correct but I want the range of 0.01<0<0.05 to have the salmon color. (is because I have many dataframes like this and some have various of values)

Comment: Do you know the `hex` or `rgb` of you wanted color?

Comment: yes, #DE0A0A  and ##FA8072 should be similar